# How to update references in cells after inserting columns

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a worksheet with multiple columns, in it columns D and E reference columns J, K, L to perform a calculation. I have a macro that does a couple of things, but the most important is that it inserts a new "D and E" and "J, K, L" for the user to work through. I currently have the worksheet set up such that it correctly adds the new columns, and adds the formulas and data validations necessary for those columns, but I can't figure out how to get the cell references to work properly.

Currently the following happens:
E references J, K, L
After inserting new columns, E becomes G, and still works correctly.
However, The new E references the columns incorrectly. It's referencing N, O, and P where it should instead be referencing M, N, and O.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I could get the formulas to update automatically after inserting the new columns?

Answer (score 0):

Im thinking you used excel interface to help you build your macro. Many times excel does not use relative references. That is easily fixed using offset function in vba. Post the vba code and I will try to further help you. Otherwise youtube on offset function and that should get you going.